# AngularJS, reinit (update page) on external event

Tags: angularjs, firebase, phonegap

I have angularjs mobile app, after opening chat page messages being loaded:

```
myApp.controller('ChatControllerGlobal',function($scope,global) {
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: serverURL+'&act=get_chat',
      withCredentials: true,
    }).then(function successCallback(data) {
        $scope.messages = data.data;
        $scope.loader = false;
        $scope.content = true;
      });

});
```

and now by external event i need somehow to reinit controller (load new messages):

```
window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function(data) {
    // some code here to reload new chat messages
});
```

Is there any not dirty way to reinit controller or call controller function?

Comment: Side note: I'm not sure if you have a special case that requires you to not use built in services like `$http`, but FYI if you use `$http` and its promises you won't have to do `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: @FrankModica, updated code, looks more angular now =)

Answer (score 1):

You could create an injectable service from your Firebase plugin. Then inject that service into your controller, and call a function that gets your messages:

```
myApp
  .factory('firebase', function ($window) {
      return $window.FirebasePlugin;
  });

myApp.controller('ChatControllerGlobal', function ($scope, $http, firebase) {
  getMessages();

  firebase.onNotificationOpen(function (data) {
    getMessages();
  });

  function getMessages() {
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: serverURL + '&act=get_chat',
      withCredentials: true,
    }).then(function successCallback(data) {
      $scope.messages = data.data;
      $scope.loader = false;
      $scope.content = true;
    });
  }
});
```

This way you can mock the `firebase` service in unit tests.

Comment: Got in an issue, i need to receive those notifications in several controllers, i will define  `firebase.onNotificationOpen(function (data) {` in several places all previous ones are stopping to work...

Comment: Right, now you can call `onNotificationOpen` wherever you need. Isn't that good?

Comment: I made it a bit another way because `onNotificationOpen` fires only one time at last declaration, so i had to create custom event and fire it from onNotificationOpen %)